# How to include JavaScript detail button on visual force page?

Tags: visualforce

I want to know is it possible to include the JavaScript custom button on visual-force page.

for e.g. we can include the delete button like

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.delete,id)}" value="Delete" />
```

Comment: yes you can add this.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to include a custom button on a Visualforce page. The closest you can get is to either replicate the functionality with an `<apex:commandButton />` or to move the javascript functionality into a static resource, then include that resource in your custom button using `{!REQUIRESCRIPT()}` and include it on your visualforce page by using `<apex:includeScript />`, then wire it to an `<apex:commandButton />`. This second approach might involve more overhead (and some refactoring of your button javascript), but saves you from having to update the same code in two places.